# Script out Agent job using asp c# or TSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have an asp application to start/stop/enable/disable/create/schedule SQL agent jobs. Now i want to add DELETE job functionality to it. before deleting i would like to take a backup of the job and store it in a table. Can somebody help me to how script out Agent jobs using C#?

I heard about using SMOs but im not aware of it. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using TSQL.
With SQL Server Management Studio, you can get a "master" script, for deleting and creating the job.

Open SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on your job, select "Script Job as" and then "DROP And CREATE to", or "DROP To".

A script is displayed in the query Result. You only have to customize the script.

Note : if you need more informatin about the job (for instance the GUIDs), follow this link : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/.